# Read only Alfresco profile

Tags: active-directory, ldap, user-profile, alfresco

I sync'ed Alfresco with AD via LDAP successfully but now I have read only profiles in Alfresco.  How do I make those profiles editable?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is intended.

Modifications must be done using Active Directory, since you sync from it. It is not two-ways.